# Can't use stopProgagation and preventDefault to stop opening a link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseevent

I can't seem to get preventDefault or stopPropagation to work on some types of links. I'd like to write a program to highlight an element on a webpage and save that element as I click it. I'd like to be able to click multiple elements on the page so the program should avoid navigate out of the page. The program fails in some cases. For examples, if I go to https://www.yahoo.com, past the program in the console log and click the ads image, it will open the link. The same happens when I visit https://www.amazon.com and click on the image above "Ad Feedback". It appears it just doesn't work on the ads links.

I tried this program on both firefox and chrome browser. The program works on majority of the links but fails on Ads link. By viewing the HTML source I can't figure out why it fails and how it can be fixed. The program is shown below. Just copy it to run in console.

```
var highlightDiv = document.createElement('div');
highlightDiv.id = 'testeditor123abc';
document.body.insertBefore(highlightDiv, document.body.firstChild);
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

document.addEventListener('mouseover', processElement, true);
document.addEventListener('click', captureElement, true);

function processElement(e) {
  let elem = e.target;
  let elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  highlightDiv.style.top = elemRect.top+'px';
  highlightDiv.style.left = elemRect.left+'px';
  highlightDiv.style.width = elemRect.width+'px';
  highlightDiv.style.height = elemRect.height+'px';  
  highlightDiv.style.transition = '0.1s';
  highlightDiv.style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)';
  highlightDiv.style.borderColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)';
  highlightDiv.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  highlightDiv.style.borderStyle = 'dashed';
  highlightDiv.style.position = 'fixed';
  highlightDiv.style.zIndex = '999999999999999';
  highlightDiv.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}

function captureElement(e) {
  console.log('Mouse X: ', mouseX);
  console.log('Mouse Y: ', mouseY);
  let element = e.target;
  let viewportDimensions = {};
  viewportDimensions.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  viewportDimensions.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  let command = {};
  console.log('Element:');
  console.log(element);
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I hope the program would stop sending me to other page for any element I click on the page. I greatly appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: The ad links are most likely adding their own click event handlers to stop link hijacking.  `preventDefault()` only prevents the default behaviour of the links, not other click handlers (or mouse down, mouse up).

Comment: Selenium IDE's target locator is able to prevent opening such links. I checked their codes and they're calling the same functions. Not sure how they got it to work: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/blob/master/packages/selenium-ide/src/content/targetSelector.js